# how to handle exception this org.springframework.integration.MessageHandlingException: HTTP request execution failed for URI [{outBoundUrl}]

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-integration

While using spring integration http outbound getting this exception:

```
org.springframework.integration.MessageHandlingException: HTTP request execution failed for URI [{outBoundUrl}]

org.springframework.integration.MessageHandlingException: HTTP request execution failed for URI [{outBoundUrl}]
    at org.springframework.integration.http.outbound.HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler.java:377)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:134)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:102)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:157)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.doSend(MessagingTemplate.java:288)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(MessagingTemplate.java:318)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(MessagingTemplate.java:239)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.convertSendAndReceive(MessagingTemplate.java:274)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.doSendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:224)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.sendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:203)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invokeGatewayMethod(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:306)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.doInvoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:269)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:260)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.getAvCache(Unknown Source)
    at com.sonata.integration.CoffeeIntegration.main(CoffeeIntegration.java:23)
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error: Connection refused: connect; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:453)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:409)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:384)
    at org.springframework.integration.http.outbound.HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler.java:351)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:69)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:157)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:378)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:473)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:203)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:290)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:306)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:995)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:931)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:849)
    at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(SimpleClientHttpRequest.java:69)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:52)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:438)
    ... 22 more
```

how to resolve this exception

Please give me any clue

Comment: Seems like the placeholder {outBoundUrl} doesn't get substituted.

Answer (score 1):

Please, upgrade to more actual Spring Integration version. The issue for property place holder has been [fixed](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3526).

From other side there is a `cause`, which indicates a reason of the `MessageHandlingException`.

So, take a look to it or just share a StackTrace here and we'll try to help you.

Comment: I just share my exception please refer that and give me any suggestion for that exception

Comment: As I said: placeholder issue has been fixed. the `Connection refused: connect` isn't related to Spring Integration. You target service doesn't work. Wrong `url`?

Answer (score 0):

SSL certificate issue
To verify disable the SSL enable property from httpd.conf of HTTP server